# Reference request: excess normal bundle and derived pullback

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, derived-functors

Consider a fiber square
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    X' @>i'>> Y'\\
    @V g V V @VV f V\\
    X @>>i> Y,
\end{CD}
where $i$ and $i'$ are regular immersions, and consider the *excess normal bundle* defined by the exact sequence
$$ 0 \to N_{X'/Y'} \to N_{X/Y} \to E \to 0, $$
which measures the failure of $f$ to be transverse to $i(X)$ in the sense of differential topology.

Does anyone know a reference for the fact that $L_j f^*(i_* \mathcal O_X) = \Lambda^j E^*$?

If $f$ is also a regular immersion then this is SGA 6, VII, Proposition 2.5, although that's not the friendliest reference.  If need be I can derive the fact I want from that special case, but I'd rather just have it off the shelf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See Lemma 3.2 in the following paper: R. W. Thomason, *Les K-groupes d'un schéma éclaté et une formule d'intersection excédentaire*, Invent. Math. **112**, 195--215 (1993), [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01232430).

Comment: Perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, Proposition 1.28 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.7994 may help.

Comment: Thanks Sasha, this is very nice too!

Comment: I have an idle dream of writing a sequel to Huybrechts' Fourier-Mukai book that includes all these little things that I need all the time. Or maybe you can do it, you're much energetic than I am.

Comment: I have no experience in writing books, so I would be afraid to start.